# Keyboard shortcut in R / radian terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, vscode-r

I have a keyboard shortcut to use `ALT+-` to insert `->` in R files, and it works.

```
{
        "key": "alt+-",
        "command": "type",
        "when": "editorLangId == r || editorLangId == rmd || editorLangId == quarto && editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "text": " <- "
        }
    }
```

But it does not (unsurprisingly) work in the R / radian terminal because of the `when` condition.

How can I make it also work in the R / radian terminal?

Comment: I saw I could do that in `radian`, but I would prefer to have the config in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [radian's documentation](https://github.com/randy3k/radian?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-key-bindings), the key binding for inserting `->` is by using `esc + -` whether you accessed `radian` through VScode or directly in the terminal.

You can custom them also in your `.radian_profile` or `radian/profile` using the code below

```
  options(
    radian.escape_key_map = list(
        list(key = "-", value = " <- ")
    ),
    radian.ctrl_key_map = list(
        list(key = "right", value = " %>% ")
    )
  )
```